# to remove href attr from all the anchor tags using Reg Ex

Tags: regex, replace, printing, href

i am trying to remove  href attr from all the anchor tags using Reg Ex,for print page.
Although i need the text value in anchors.

Answer (score 3):

Couldn't you just style your links using CSS? You could create two separate styles: one for "normal" web visits, and one for print. In the print-style, you don't visually enhance the links.

Answer (score 0):

Never parse markup with regular expressions.  BAD!

http://htmlparsing.icenine.ca